# Memory Leak, possibly from unknown Microsoft Driver

Tags: windows-10, memory, drivers, memory-leaks

Task manager lists about 800 MB taken from startup, and the performance tab and resource monitor show about 3.9 GB from startup. After about 24 hours, it will be at ~13 GB. Two days, even sleeping, and system suffers trying to even switch programs.

I have attempted closing programs that run at start. I switched browsers to see if it was chrome or an extension on it. I closed hardware-bundled software, like Logitech's keyboard customization centre, or the AMD Radeon control centre. After a few hours, memory usage had risen to ~7-8 GB, and I couldn't identify what program was causing this.

I searched online to find this is a textbook case of memory leak. I installed RAMMap to try and find the culprit, and honestly, not too certain how to actually locate the culprit using it. Used more tools I found online, and I got poolmon (memory pool monitor). I ran it with `/b` for the correct ordering? I don't remember where I saw a lot of this information on how to use it, but I believe that argument left the one I wanted at the top.

At first I thought it was a header or total that I was reading, because the tag was "Time" instead of a random string of capitals and lower case. When I counted the allocated and freed memory from the rows below it, I saw that it wasn't a total at all. After a few hours, the "Time" row had allocated over 8,000,000 more than it had freed (it was about 9mil minus 1mil)(I think it is in kilobytes, but if it is just in bytes then this may not be the problem- and I would need indicating of that). Some of the guides I saw online suggested that it could be allocating digits more than freed, but even the second most allocated-freed was maybe ~1000 apart.

I navigated to the system32/drivers folder, and used `findstr /m /l Time *.sys` to find the driver associated. That turned up a huge list of drivers, so using advice from a site, I used `findstr /m /l hTime *.sys`. This brought up three things:

```
FINDSTR: Cannot open FACEIT.sys
FINDSTR: Cannot open FACEIT2.sys
KNetPwrDepBroker.sys
```

So the first two are actually missing things, but unless I'm mistaken, FACEIT refers to the csgo alternative matchmaking client I have used in the past. Not sure why it has system files, but I think its extensive anticheat is probably why. Since I don't currently use it, I uninstalled it. Then, the last of the three, is `KNetPwrDepBroker.sys`. I don't know anything about this file other than it is signed by Microsoft. All attempts to Google what this file is just ends with people asking if it is malware. There are one or two sites offering a download of this file, but I don't trust that at all- if there is an error with this file, I'd prefer Windows to replace it, not some website that I wouldn't trust even if I had heard of it. There is also a bleepingcomputer forum post about a memory leak- but, unfortunately, it wasn't actually related to this file, it was just contained in a large log.

I had Windows run all optional updates, went through problem drivers- there was one AMD PCIe encryption driver that was missing, but fixing that hasn't changed anything. I run the tag search now, and I get options two and three still returning- So uninstalling FACEIT didn't remove the "FINDSTR: Cannot open FACEIT2.sys" from the system. This memory leak is from the last month or four, so while that may be a problem, even an alarming one, it probably isn't my issue. `KNetPwrDepBroker.sys` is still there, ofc, and I'd like to know what it is so I can uninstall the driver and reinstall. I am assuming it is a driver.

All of this, and I may just be misidentifying the cause. Every site explaining on how to use RAMMap to identify basically says "Mapped file looks big, go to physical pages and find the problem" and I can't even tell if there is a problem. But If I run almost nothing at startup and am still having this issue, could it not be a driver?

Edits: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ6S4.jpg Small post album from comments. Includes two screenshots of RAMMap I made over night, and I see little to no change. Performance also tab also stayed at 4GB overnight. This may be good, I still can't identify why the system is taking 4GB when all running processes should take less than 1GB... but I can just start running apps one at a time to find if any memory leak is left.

Comment: In Task Manager's *Details* tab sort by memory and post a screenshot.

Comment: @user1292580 Cannot post images under 10 rep, let's see if it allows this link: https://imgur.com/a/tdJRgQC 

Computer up for a couple of hours, RAMMap and poolmon are running, AnyDesk so I can check in. I tried to shut down other running programs, but things like ASUS Armory constantly reopen, I left them. 

According to the performance tab, at time of screenshot, 4GB are being used.

Comment: All your programs, except RAMMAP64, seem to be running normally. Edit the link into your question. Now post from the *Performance* tab in Task Manager when Memory is selected.

Comment: @user1292580 Post edited. Used memory didn't rise over the last 9 hours. I'm still cautious about performance saying 4GB used when processes add up to less than 1GB, and would love an explanation of that. I used RAMMap to clear working sets, and it drops to 1.4GB, and I assume it'll climb back to 4GB. As for the leak itself- and I assume a leak wouldn't stop at 4GB- it was present before the last restart to get this last test going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong.

There is no point clearing working sets. Windows randomly does this on a per process page at a time anyway.

4 Gb is normal.

You are actually using 13 GB - 4 GB + 9 GB for cache. That 9 GB is counted under both *Cached* and *Available*.

Hover over the elements in the bar graph for more info.

Here is an article about Intel's Virtual Machines/Virtual Memory memory management implemented by Microsoft. https://www.labri.fr/perso/betrema/winnt/ntvmm.html

Apart from limits being larger the only major change is the file cache. A physical page will be in the file cache. It may also be mapped into the standby list (memory removed from a program but still in memory in case the program wants it back) or program's address space.

Working set is the amount of physical memory in the program's address space. However all the rest of its' memory are probably sitting on the standby list. By default program have small working sets but a program can change it (as video editors will).

This allows Windows to do quick memory management if a program suddenly needs lots of memory access or when starting programs.

Comment: The reason I cleared working sets before is because that was the only alternative to restarting when the computer was reporting 15.5GB in use when it was actually using less than 3GB. So, if I understand what you are saying now, is that the 4GB on startup is not indicative of useless assigned memory, even though emptying sets it only rose back up to 2GB. That's good news.

Comment: I thought the last restart I performed did not change drivers or a Windows update, so it must have been a program I closed. I'll continue using the computer as normal, and if I see a memory leak, still, I'll open programs one at a time until I find the one that does it. Since that is different than the problem I asked the question for, and I'm confident in being able to find a problem now that it exists, I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Programs leak memory. Drivers can leak memory. But drivers are tested by MS after the hardware company tests it if Windows Update give them to you. RamMap is useless. Use Task Manager to identify the program or service. Use WinDbg or Process Explorer to investigate that program.